# Matrix Inverse broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting, inverse

I am trying to calculate `Rij = Aij * Bij/Cij` by Numpy broadcasting.

`B1 * np.linalg.inv(C1)` gives a singular matrix error.

I have also tried doing this. It gave me some values but I am not super sure if it is correct.
`D = B1 / C1[..., None]`

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv


A = [[(i+j)/2000 for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]
B = [[(i-j)/2000 for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]
C = [[((i+1)/(j+1))/2000 for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]



def numpy_task3_part_A(A,B,C):
    A1 = np.array(A)
    B1 = np.array(B)
    C1 = np.array(C)
    D = B1 / C1[..., None]
    Rij = A1 @ D
    return Rij


A1 = np.array(A)
B1 = np.array(B)
C1 = np.array(C)
print(C1.shape)
print(B1.shape)
print(A1.shape)

numpy_task3_part_A(A,B,C)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you perform a test? Make 3 small matrices (small, 3x3) where you know what the result would be. Then check if the result is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

you want to do element-wise matrix multiplication and division, the normal `*` and `/` operators do the element-wise operation.

numpy `@` operator does matrix product as studied in any algebra course, and dividing by the `inv` of the matrix actually compute the matrix inverse which is not an element-wise divsion.

you just need to do this.

```py
R = A * B / C
```